# External command does not execute completely - Java

Tags: java, ffmpeg, runtime.exec

So, I am building a program that converts .flv files to other formats.
For that I'm using ffmpeg which does its job perfectly when executing it via command line. For example:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\test.flv -acodec libmp3lame -y C:\test.mp3
```

This example works like a charm - there isn't a single problem when executing the command.

BUT when I try to execute the same command from within a Java class a problem occurs. I do this in a try-catch block:

```
System.out.println("Start");
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c ffmpeg -i C:\test.flv -acodec libmp3lame -y C:\test.mp3");
System.out.println("End");
```

The console prints "Start". It starts converting and it doesn't finish.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: the \t in C:\test is going to be passed as C:<tab>est, by the way... you need escape the backslash.

Comment: `ffmpeg` is surely not a `DOS` command. It's a command-line program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the problem was solved in a very unexpected way. I just had to read the output that the execution generates. And, voila, the file was converted.

```
InputStream in = p.getErrorStream();
int c;
while ((c = in.read()) != -1)
{
    System.out.print((char)c);
}
in.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

1. `cmd /c ffmpeg -i C:\test.flv -acodec libmp3lame -y C:\test.mp3` is **not a command**. (You probably end up getting an `IOException` which causes the `"End"` to be suppressed.)

   `cmd` is the command you want to execute, and the rest of the string are arguments. Use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) or [`Runtime.exec(String[] cmdarray)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29)
2. You need to wait for the process to finish. Call

   ```
   p.waitFor();
   ```

   after starting the process. Here's a link for the documentation of [`Process.waitFor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29).

Comment: You're right, though I suspect something may be amiss elsewhere.  At present the program *shouldn't* wait for the process and so `End` should be printed to the console almost immediately

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried control String **"**, something like :

```
cmd "ffmpeg" -i "C:\test.flv" -acodec "libmp3lame" -y "C:\test.mp3"
```

or

```
cmd "ffmpeg -i C:\test.flv -acodec libmp3lame -y C:\test.mp3"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not a DOS command. It is a console command line, from any flavour of Microsoft Windows.

You can do it using `p.waitFor()` as @aioobe explains or you can use a wrapper Java API for FFMPEG like [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/index), it would be easy to use, and it has LGPL.